# onAfterDispatch is getting called differently

Tags: plugin-events, system-plugin

I have a system plugin that is doing something very simple. The issue is that locally it works fine, but on a live server the events seam to be differing and the plugin is not getting triggered.

Both systems are identical in Joomla version and all other aspects.

I call an URL like this:

```
https://www.mysite.com?myevent=webhook&nolangfilter=1&id=123
```

Inside the system plugin this is the important part:

```
class MyPluginwebhook extends CMSPlugin implements SubscriberInterface
{
    protected $db;
    protected $app;
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'onAfterDispatch' => 'checkWebhook',
        ];
    }

    public function checkWebhook()
    {
        if ($this->app->isClient('site') && $this->app->input->getCmd('myevent') == 'webhook') {
            // here some stuff with document gets done, so the "onAfterDispatch" event needs to be used in favor of "onAfterRoute".
            echo "success";
            die();
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Here is the debugging stack showing the different flows locally and on remote:

localy everything works fine:

```
Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   ()  JROOT\plugins\system\mypluginwebhook\src\Extension\MyPluginwebhook.php:70
2   Joomla\Plugin\System\MyPluginwebhook\Extension\MyPluginwebhook->checkWebhook()  JROOT\libraries\vendor\joomla\event\src\Dispatcher.php:486
3   Joomla\Event\Dispatcher->dispatch() JROOT\libraries\src\Application\EventAware.php:111
4   Joomla\CMS\Application\WebApplication->triggerEvent()   JROOT\libraries\src\Application\SiteApplication.php:213
5   Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->dispatch()  JROOT\libraries\src\Application\SiteApplication.php:249
6   Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute() JROOT\libraries\src\Application\CMSApplication.php:293
7   Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT\includes\app.php:61
8   require_once()  JROOT\index.php:32
```

on remote EventAware is not getting called:

```
Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   ()  JROOT/components/com_content/src/Model/ArticleModel.php:218
2   Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Model\ArticleModel->getItem() JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/View/AbstractView.php:146
3   Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\AbstractView->get() JROOT/components/com_content/src/View/Article/HtmlView.php:110
4   Joomla\Component\Content\Site\View\Article\HtmlView->display()  JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:645
5   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->display() JROOT/components/com_content/src/Controller/DisplayController.php:121
6   Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Controller\DisplayController->display()   JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:678
7   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute() JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ComponentDispatcher.php:143
8   Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch()   JROOT/components/com_content/src/Dispatcher/Dispatcher.php:56
9   Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Dispatcher\Dispatcher->dispatch() JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:361
10  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:208
11  Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->dispatch()  JROOT/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:249
12  Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:293
13  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT/includes/app.php:61
14  require_once()  JROOT/index.php:32
```

Comment: A very common cause of issues where something works in the local environment, I am assuming your local environment is Windows, and the same code in a hosted environment is there is a mis-match in the required case of such things as a class name. For example myclass is fine on a windows environment but needs to be Myclass on the nix environment because Windows treats the `m` and `M` as being the same.

Comment: Thanks, but the classnames are fine.

Comment: OK, but are all the names of the files in the correct case? If you have a letter in a filename in the wrong case then Windows will forgive you and still open the file, but linux won't.

Answer (score 1):

The second stack trace shows an exception was thrown during the execution of a component. In such case `onAfterDispatch` event is not triggered. Instead, the application dispatches `onError` event for plugins to handle the error/exception. I'm not sure what your goal is but in case you need an endpoint for the plugin, you should use [AJAX](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface) component instead of appending random parameters to existing URLs.

Comment: There are no random parameters. The exception is thrown, because Joomla is not getting the option parameter set, so it fails to boot the component. The question is, why that only happens online, because like i said, both instances are same.

Comment: In this case the exception is thrown because you are stuffing random parameters into the URL of home menu item. The component reads the ID parameter and throws an exception because article with ID 123 is not found. Whatever plugins you've seen use this pattern predate AJAX component. You should use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but there are no random parameters. The only parameter is the ID seen in the URL, that is needed. Still not understanding why locally (which is the same instance with same content) is working. However, I switched now to J4 API access. Same results get returned but much better than on an event based system plugin. Thanks again.